# Largest range of uniformly distributed float values?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the distribution of float values on the real number line.

I wrote this code to count the number of *uniformly distributed* representable values in a range (-R,R) where R is a power of **10** (also tried with powers of 2):

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<24; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            float R = (float) Math.pow(10, i); //(2<<i);
            float Rstep = Math.ulp(R);
            for(float x = -R; x <= R; x+=Rstep)
                count++;
            System.out.println(R+" "+count+" "+Math.ulp(R));
        }
    }
}
```

I was surprised by the variance in results i.e.

```
1.0 16777217 1.1920929E-7
10.0 20971521 9.536743E-7
100.0 26214401 7.6293945E-6
1000.0 32768001 6.1035156E-5
10000.0 20480001 9.765625E-4
100000.0 25600001 0.0078125
1000000.0 32000001 0.0625
```

as I'd semi-convinced myself the number of uniformly distributed values would be 16777216 (i.e. 1<<23 for a 23bit mantissa, doubled due to the sign bit).

To put some concreteness behind this question - I'm trying to build a model (which uses SI units precise over several orders of magnitude e.g distance in km to nanometres) but have to map it into float space (for loading into a GPU). Since this is a scientific model, I need to understand where precision is lost. The plan is to snap values to a uniformly distributed range - so from the table above snap to the range (-1000,1000) would give me 32768001 exact values.

It seems counter-intuitive to me that there would be so much variance across these ranges, and why the power of 2 cases are limited.

Is anyone able to explain how to think about this?

cheers

Comment: I think you forgot about the zero.

Comment: thanks - I'm not so worried about this potential off-by-one error (although it would be good to understand) - more the variance of a factor of 2

Comment: What do you mean by “uniformly distributed”? The only intervals including zero where `float` values have uniform spacing is from -2**-125 (about -2.35e-38) to +2**-125 and all subintervals of that. In that interval, the spacing is 2**-149 (about 1.40e-45). Beyond that, the step size varies; the distribution of representable values is not uniform.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: [-1.0, +1.0] is the unique maximizer for any binary FP format, since it is the only power of two that is also a power of ten.  Questioner miscounted by taking an ULP *larger* than 1.0 as his unit, which is too large by a factor of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really print the floats in hexadecimal, it would be much clearer then.

Your estimate of “16777216 (i.e. 1<<23 for a 23bit mantissa, doubled due to the sign bit)” is only half what you can expect. The best case is to start from a number that looks like -0x1.FFF…pX in hexadecimal, that is, the opposite of a number just below a power of two. When repeatedly adding the initial ULP, you will indeed traverse all values of the significand with exponent X. That's 1<<23 steps as you inferred. When you are done with that you will be **half as close to zero as you started**. The same number of steps will take you to zero (with exponents lower than X), then double the number of steps again for positive values.

So, that's 1<<25 (~32000000) or so evenly spaced floats that can be found in-between any near-power of two and its opposite. You get about that number of steps with 1000 because 1000 is just under the power of two 1024.

The worst case, as you noticed, is to start with a number just above a power of two, say 0x1.00001pX. Then you traverse almost no values with exponent X, but instead start visiting values with lower exponents immediately. You end up visiting only half as many values as you would have if you had started from 0x1.FFF…pX

---

**NOTE:** the notation `-0x1.123defpX` should be interpreted as -0x1.123def * 2 ^ X. Perhaps your programming language accepts it for input and/or output of floating-point values. To re-iterate, it is very convenient when trying to understand what is happening.